# Tool to change user information in AD and Exchange

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there any tool that can be used by HR to fill and change user details in AD and Exchange?
(eg: company, department, telephone numbers, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a delegation tool. What versions of Windows Server/Exchange are you using? Something like Directory Update or Directory Manager would work for this if you only need a subset of users to have the ability to edit entries for the organization.

http://www.directory-update.com/

Comment: Directory Manager seems to be the tool I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of tools avaiable, but none of them work without you first using delegation of control, which you appear to be lacking an understanding of. Here's an old article that explains it pretty nicely. The concept is the same whether your domain is W2K, W2K3, or W2K8.

http://www.activewin.com/win2000/step_by_step/active_directory/delegsteps.shtml

Once you've read the article and gleaned an understanding of what it is you're asking for, you can look for the appropriate tool for your needs. One I've used is [ADManager Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/download.html).

Comment: Although I've picked @ewwhite's answer, because that kind of tool is what I need, I thank you for that great article you pointed.

Answer (score 0):

AD tool is available for free at http://www.gp2x.org/adtool/

It's a command-line LDAP editing tool.
Here's a [quick usage example](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/02/manage-your-active-directory-from-linux-with-adtool/).

You may also want to check with LDAPSoft. http://www.ldapsoft.com/

They have a commercial product, LDAP Admin Tool Standard Edition, that may work with AD. I've not used it though.

Comment: These tools you mentioned are for admins. I need a tool that HR staff can use to change those informations.

Comment: Your original post had "RH" instead of "HR", so I assumed you meant RedHat Linux. That changes the context of the question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'd mistyped it.

Comment: While it's true those are admin tools, if HR wants to do it in batch jobs, like say for seasonal hires or students at a school or similar situations, you could set up a script that populates AD from info in a csv.  I've written such scripts in the past to clean up old contact info in an inherited AD.  If that's what you are looking for let me know, I see if I can dig up that script for you.